# Android: Cyclic event chain, how to avoid it?

Tags: android, android-widget

#### The problem

Similar to the question regarding Swing ( [The Elegant way to handle Cyclic Event in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399134/the-elegant-way-to-handle-cyclic-event-in-java) ) I'm looking for a elegant way to avoid a cyclic event chain where two widget views depend on each other.

More specifically I have two `EditText's`, one of them represents a weight in kg, the other the weight in lb. The user should be able to enter text in either and have the other updated as he/she types.

#### What I've tried

The only way to act on a change in the controller that I've found is to register a `TextWatcher` on each `EditText` view. But how do I elegantly avoid the circular event chain that occurs if I modify the other `EditText` in the callback.

I tried sub-classing `EditText` and bind them together without using `TextWatcher` by overloading `setText` and have that method modify the value and call `setText` of the other controller. But that doesn't work not calling `setText`, which seems to be the case when user enters text from UI and not programmatically.

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding and removing `TextWatcher's` when the controller is focused and unfocused. This has the drawback that the same mirroring code is not used when setting a controller's text programmatically (unless I programmatically set the focus as well, which is not a very nice solution, IMO).

It works fine, but I still think there's a cleaner solution out there.